# How to set dates on content using a transmogrifier pipeline

Tags: plone, data-migration, transmogrifier

I'm importing content to Plone using a transmogrifier pipeline and I need to set the dates (creation, effective and modification) on the items when creating them.

The fields I'm trying to update are: `creation_date`, `effective_date` and `modification_date` and, for Dexterity-based content types, I can confirm that the updater [works only on fields listed on the schema](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.dexterity/blob/b161bcc0be88d9090803fb39babcd4b3e6b9b1ab/transmogrify/dexterity/schemaupdater.py#L88:L91), so the ones stated before are just ignored.

What's the right way of accomplish this task? Do I have to write another pipeline section of is there something available in another package?

Comment: Can you add the exact names for the fields you are using?

Comment: Done, Martijn! anything else?

Comment: Give me a memory restore from when I still did enough Plone work to remember if those are the right names..

Comment: Hmm, careful with the naming of your fields.  One of my transmogrifier pipelines references `effectiveDate` & `expirationDate`. I can't remember why, but worth checking.